# alert dropdown menu item on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is very simple code to alert the menu item. I dont know why it does not alert on button click.

http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/xw7qx/1/

```
$( "#submit" ).click(function() {
    var test = document.getElementById("myddl");
    alert(test);
    });
```

html:

```html
Header:
<br />
<select id="myddl" name="myddl">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Twooo</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<a class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-success" id="submit" href="#fakelink"> Submit </a>
```

Comment: use document.getElementById("myddl").value http://jsfiddle.net/xw7qx/2/

Comment: Your fiddle works just fine, it alerts the value of the selected item.
However, the fiddle JavaScript is ___completely different___ from this question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try something like this ([Demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3E79y/)):

```
$(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var test = $("#myddl").val();
        alert(test);
    });
});
```

Don't mix `jQuery` and vanilla `JavaScript`.

Answer (score 0):

You should not mix jQuery and javascript, stick with jQuery its easier because in native javascript it is a pain to access the selected option in a select, you have to loop the array, compare with if, if selected and so on. I suggest that you try the following code:

If you need the text of the selected option:

```
$( "#submit" ).click(function() {
    var test = $("#mydd1 option:selected").html();
    alert(test);
});
```

Incase you need only the value tag:

```
$( "#submit" ).click(function() {
    var test = $("#mydd1 option:selected").attr("value");
    alert(test);
});
```

Comment: _"You should not mix jQuery and javascript, stick with jQuery its easier"_... Yea, that's actually bad advice. If something can easily and quickly be coded using native JS, using jQuery is a bad idea. Also: `.attr("value")`, really?

Comment: I understand the point that we should not mix native JavaScript and jQuery.  But what exactly is causing the error in OP's code?

Comment: @SidCool No its just a little hint. The main point is that document.getElementById() cant be printed like that because he needs to access the selected option and loop the array and such and thatswhy I decided to use jQuery Api selector to avoid this annoying crap.

Edited my post and added my intention for that decicison, hope that makes you guys happy...

Answer (score 0):

```
    try this

   <select id="myddl" name="myddl">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Twooo</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>

    <a class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-success" id="submit" href="#fakelink"> Submit </a>


    <script>
    $("document").ready(function() 
        {
        $('#submit').click(function()
        {
            alert($("#myddl option:selected").val())
        })
    });
    </script>
```